# Unmarshaling string with repeated fields into json

Tags: json, go

Trying to unmarshal a string into json, but my struct definitions don't work. How can it be fixed?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    x := `{
    "Header": {
        "Encoding-Type": [
            "gzip"
        ],
        "Bytes": [
            "29"
        ]
    }
}`

    type HeaderStruct struct {
        A string
        B []string
    }
    type Foo struct {
        Header HeaderStruct
    }


    var f Foo 
    if e := json.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &f); e != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed:", e)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("unmarshalled=", f)
    }

}
```

Comment: You've got no json labels on your structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of your variables don't match the names of the json keys and both of them are `[]string`. You can do

```
type HeaderStruct struct {
    A []string `json:"Encoding-Type"`
    B []string `json:"Bytes"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need json annotations to tell the unmarshaller which data goes where, also the type of `A` in your model is wrong, it should also be an array. I'm also going to change the names of your fields to something meaningful...

```
type HeaderStruct struct {
    Encoding []string `json:"Encoding-Type"`
    Bytes []string `json:"Bytes"
}
```